# how to calculate the integral with temporal data?

Tags: python, dataframe, math, integral

I would like to compute the integral of discrete signal segment Y (Y=[y1,y2,...y50]) and X is the following  datetime64[ns] object:

```
x=['2018-01-24T13:41:25.057000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.069000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.077000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.090000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.097000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.111000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.117000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.130000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.138000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.150000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.158000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.170000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.178000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.199000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.200000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.211000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.218000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.231000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.238000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.250000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.258000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.269000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.278000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.290000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.298000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.311000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.317000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.331000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.338000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.350000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.358000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.370000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.378000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.390000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.398000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.411000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.418000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.430000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.437000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.450000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.469000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.469000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.479000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.493000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.502000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.510000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.517000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.530000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.537000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.550000000']
```

My attempt is using the following python code:

Case A, with the above x:

```
f_x_tot_acc = Y
x_n = x[-1]
x_0 = x[0]
h = (x_n - x_0) / (len(f_x_tot_acc) - 1)
print('trapz [' + str(integrate.trapz(f_x_tot_acc, dx=h)) + ']')
```

The Result is: trapz [6203255447 nanoseconds]

Case B,

```
x = range(0,50)
f_x_tot_acc = Y 
x_n = x[-1]
x_0 = x[0]
h = (x_n - x_0) / (len(f_x_tot_acc) - 1)
print('trapz [' + str(integrate.trapz(f_x_tot_acc, dx=h)) + ']')
```

The Result is:  trapz [616.5507767408332].

Which is the correct one?

Many Thanks in advance,
Best Regards,
Carlo

Comment: *Almost surely* `[6203255447 nanoseconds]` can not be the correct answer.

Comment: please provide your `Y` values

Comment: @pault I dunno, it's conceivable that x contains time/date objects and arithmetic operations have been defined on such objects. The trapezoid rule is just some simple arithmetic so it's plausible that it could return another time/date object. Of course the units should be units(y) times time but if y has no units associated with it, the units of the result will just be time. Of course more info is needed. I guess what I'm saying is that it might "accidentally" be correct ... it might.

Comment: What are the elements of x? Are they strings or time/date objects? Note that the rectangle rule is actually more accurate than the trapezoid rule, and very simple, so why not just form dx = (x[k + 1] minus x[k] for k = 1, ... n - 1) and multiply that times y and add it up.

Comment: The element of x are time/date objects. In python terms, it is datetime64[ns].

Comment: the Y values are acceleration measurements expressed in ms2.